# 2011 iMac12,2 Windows 10 BootCamp SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED (igdkmd64.sys)

Tags: bootcamp, high-sierra, imac, windows

During the setup process of the Windows 10 install (where it says stuff like "getting your pc ready" or whatever), my mac BSODs with the error:

```
Stop Code: SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
What failed: igdkmd64.sys
```

[image: BSOD]

I searched google for igdkmd64.sys and it appears to be an issue with Intel iGPU drivers, but iirc (and according to system profiler), the iMac12,2 doesn't have an iGPU, just a dGPU (HD 6970M).

I booted into safe mode and opened Device Viewer and it showed an Intel iGPU, and a AMD dGPU. I tried to disable the iGPU, and then restarted, but then, Windows would not boot at all.
[image: No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key]

Comment: Win10 isn't supported for that model - https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-2.7-27-inch-aluminum-mid-2011-thunderbolt-specs.html - you might do better installing WIn7 & updating from within Windows.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've tried using my Windows 7 disk and during the Windows 7 installation, it said that the disk was corrupt (makes since because the disk is old and kind of scrated up), so I tried making a bootable flashdrive with both Boot Camp Assistant, and Rufus on a Windows PC, but when booting into either of those flash drives, I get the same error as in the second picture of the original post. When I open the boot picker by holding alt/option down on boot, It showed a new external EFI drive, but when selecting to boot off of it, the whole machine haults and I have to force power it off.

Comment: Old Macs don't like installing Win from USB, they prefer CD. They also don't want EFI, they want to be able to see the old style protected MBR which makes them think it's a BIOS install not EFI. Perhaps try an older Boot Camp.